# is it possible to fill address lead fields automatically with geolocalization from within salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, geolocation, google-map

I would want customize my salesforce1 app so that we can add a new lead and auto-fill the address lead fields with a location button using the geolocation feature of my mobile device.

Would it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is really more of a Javascript question and should be asked on Stack Overflow, but you can combine [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map) and [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) to get what you need. No guarantees as to accuracy.